# Change <item> property programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to change the background of a button for showing the progress of a running background process. I'm using a drawable composed of two colors so now I need to change programmatically the top and bottom properties of those `<item>`s in the following layer-list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:bottom="20dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:top="30dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#000000" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

I'm not being able to select the `<item>` elements and modify them from java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the XML would not help anyway as Android does not use them at runtime. Instead, have a look at the [LayerDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html) because that's what is created from your XML and used at Runtime.

So basically you could do something like so and continue from there:
LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable)mButton.getBackground();

A **better/simpler way** however would probably be to create your own Drawable class, which would be rather simple as you only have two rectangles to draw.

Comment: A custom Drawable class was the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just create the same xml file with another item values and set new background for your button. Seems you can't change these values in runtime.

Comment: I need to be able to set specific values in order to show the current status of the background task. This can not be possible with another static xml file.